# Privacy Restrictions on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

If I post a status on Facebook, but restrict a specific someone from seeing it -  Will they still be able to see it if a mutual friend comments on it or likes it ? (No one is tagged, just a status with a picture).

Answer (score 2):

No, if you restrict the status post, it will never be visible to that specific person. Else, the restriction would not make any sense.